# Weird user in shell

Tags: shell, osx, prompt

I use iTerm on OS X 10.10
When I start iTerm I get the weird user

```
 unknownA988274AC:~ myUserName$:
```

That was not there before. Before there was

```
 myUserName$:
```

Any ideas where that comes from?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your Macintosh has been changed accidentally. What you see at the prompt at the terminal is a name assigned by your DHCP server with your MAC address appended. You can rename it by,

- Go to <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> and click on <kbd>Sharing</kbd>. Change the `Computer Name`.
- Once you have done that, reboot your Mac. A standard name may look like "Steve Jobs' MacBook." Just personalize this with your own name. And at the prompt it would appear like `Steve-Jobs-MacBook-Pro:~ steve$`

You can refer to [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/) to customize your terminal prompt.

Comment: Cool. Any ideas what could have caused the change?! I am sure I did not mess around with the DHCP Server

Comment: some program / app has changed it explicitly (or may NOT have a name in your case).

Comment: Could that be a virus or something?!

Comment: I am not certain about it, but after cold reboot you can check `/var/log/system.log` for more info.

Comment: it appears that either your system name was empty, or your shell's prompt string (PS1) changed.

Comment: DHCP has the ability to receive a hostname from the DHCP server, whoch also gives you your IP address. This, your Mac will have several hostnames. The one handed out via DHCP is taking precedence for some reason.